# Java Wildcard help Class<T> to List<Class<T>>, possible?

Tags: java, list, object, search, wildcard

I haven't coded in a long time and have lost my grip with wildcards.

I have this neat little function which works great

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> GetObjects(List<?> list, Class<T> c){
    ArrayList<T> objects = new ArrayList();     
    for(Object o : list){
        if(c.isInstance(o)){
            objects.add(c.cast(o));
        }
    }       
    return objects;
}
```

However I would like it to be able to accept a list of classes and do something like this

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> GetMultipleObjects(List<?> list, List<Class<T>> classes){
        ArrayList<T> objects = new ArrayList();     
        for(Object o : list){
            for(Class c : classes){
            if(c.isInstance(o)){
                objects.add(c.cast(o));
            }
            }
        }       
        return objects;
    }
```

This obviously isn't possible in hindsight.

Comment: What are  you expecting with a `List<Class<T>>`?  `T` only has one class.

Comment: What would you do with multiple classes?  You'd just get out one list of all the different types mushed together.

Comment: Also define "doesn't work". For now only problem I suspect is in line `objects.add(c.cast(o));` because `c` is raw `Class` instead of `Class<T>` so `cast` returns `Object` not `T` which is expected for `ArrayList<T> objects`.

Comment: I see my issue, ArrayList<T>. I'll use a interface.

Comment: @TheOnlyWAR10CK93, no, it's not clear.  If I passed in `Arrays.asList(Integer.class, String.class)`, what would I get back?  A `List<Object>`?  What would be the use of that?

Answer (score 1):

Louis is correct in the comments: there's no sensible way to define this function in Java.

Java doesn't have disjunctive types -- that is, there is no way to express a concept like "a type that is either a `String` or an `Integer`". The closest you have is to find a common supertype -- since all instantiable types inherit from `Object` (modulo primitives, but let's set those aside for now), you are always guaranteed to be able to find a common supertype, although it may simply be `Object`, which is not typically very useful.

To illustrate why this is the case, think about what kinds of things this function could be used for. I see two cases:

**Case 1**: You want to filter to where a type is a subtype of one or more types which all share a common supertype, and return a list of the supertype. You can easily do this by using a wildcard type together with the type parameter:

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(
    List<?> input,
    List<? extends Class<? extends T>> subtypesOfT) {
  // implementation exactly as you have it
}
```

But in most cases, this is going to be equivalent to just using your original function and passing the supertype instead. E.g. with your original function you can just pass `Number.class` and get back a `List<Number>` where the values in the list may be `Double` or `Integer` or `Float`. The only way this would be useful would be if you wanted to filter out a `List<Number>` from a `List<?>`, but also only include *some* subtypes of `Number`... e.g. you could pass `asList(Double.class, Integer.class)` and get back a `List<Number>`. But I'm dubious that this would be particularly useful, especially in this general of a form.

**Case 2**: Alternatively, you could have the case where you want to take a `List<?>` and filter it to contain only values of an arbitrary set of other types. In this case, there is no `T` to unify to unless you compute one, so the best you can do is to return a `List<Object>` (or, equivalently in this case if the list is read-only, a `List<?>`). For that you don't need the method to be generic at all: simply use an `ArrayList<Object>` to construct the return value and it will work fine.

If you're doing this in a sufficiently metaprogramming-y way, you might want to have a way to build a `List<T>` where `T` is the most specific common supertype that all values from the `List<?>` can be assigned to. This is also doable, but you'll need to find `T` first. Here's one way you could do that:

```
private static Class<?> findCommonSupertype(List<Class<?>> types) {
  Class<?> result = types.get(0);
  for (Class<?> type : types) {
    // Keep going as long as result is a supertype of the current type.
    if (result.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
      continue;
    }
    // Skip interfaces since they unify with any class type (unless
    // the class is final, which we don't check for here).
    if (result.isInterface() && !type.isInterface()) {
      result = type;
    } else if (type.isInterface()) {
      continue;
    }
    // Otherwise, scan up through the inheritance hierarchy to find a
    // new type that can serve as a common supertype for type and result.
    Class<?> supertype = type;
    while (!supertype.isAssignableFrom(result)) {
      supertype = supertype.getSuperclass();
      if (supertype == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            type + " and " + result + " do not share a common supertype");
      }
    }
    result = supertype;
  }
  return result;
}
```

That said, even if you had such a function, it still wouldn't be particularly useful, because you could build a `List<T>` but you wouldn't be able to statically know what `T` is (since it would be computed dynamically), so I don't think this is really what you're after either.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, It had been over a year since I looked at my code. I realized how stupid I was being halfway through the comments. Thank you for your code though, there are some really nice example of use of generic types in there.